# Exclude an Entire Type ( Class ) from Serializing

Tags: c#, xml

I want to know if there is a way to use the [XmlIgnore] tag on an entire type(A class )

So the deal is I have three particular classes 
A Base Class which is being Extended by a class A and a Class B.

I want everything in Class A to be Serialized but Nothing in Class B should be Serialized.

I tried adding the [XmlIgnore] tag to all properties of class B but that was no good because ,
1. Some properties are overridden from the base class
2. Some Properties are inherited from the Base class.

Anyway I can do this ??
Isn't there like a way to ignore an entire type when serializing to xml

Comment: Only public objects get serialized so removing public will work.

Comment: Thats not a good solution because I need the properties to be public for a reason

Comment: Then create public interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to add XMLIgnore tag to each property in the class.

Comment: Some Properties are not in the class B but are inherited from the Base class , hence they will still show up in the xml

Comment: It sounds like if you don't want the properties from A to be serialized in B, then maybe you shouldn't inherit A.  I don't think there's a way around this.

Comment: I want all properties in Class A to be Serialized , I just Don't want any Properties in Class B to be Serialized

Comment: Gotcha.  Have you tried the [NonSerialized()] attribute?